# Change cursor of selected tab in a QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I wonder if it's possible to change the cursor of the selected tab of a `QTabWidget`. I mean : I would like to have an arrow for the selected tab and the "hand" for the others. I was able to set the "hand" for the 4 tabs of the widget, but not individually.

Can I do that?

Thanks

---EDIT---
I have access to the `QTabBar`of the `QTabWidget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `QTabBar`, turn on mouse tracking (`setMouseTracking(true)`) in it's constructor, in `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)` call `tabAt(const QPoint& position) const` and `currentIndex() const`.  If they return the same number use `setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor)`, otherwise use `unsetCursor()` to return to the normal arrow cursor (remember to call the parent class implementation first).

I assume you have access to the `QTabBar` because you have derived from `QTabWidget`, otherwise you will have to subclass that to be able to set your new `QTabBar` derived class.